# HTTP: what is a good empty request to test authentication?

Tags: ruby, http, jira-rest-api

I am writing a small Ruby program that connects to a web service. The program prompts for username and password credentials, and I would like to ensure that they are correct before I proceed with other important business.

Is there any simple HTTP GET/POST request that I can send to the web server to authenticate the credentials?

Also note that I have little experience working with web services, so I also am not sure if this approach is a good idea in the first place...

EDIT here is my source code so far. I am using the [JIRA Ruby gem](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/jira-ruby/0.1.14/JIRA) FYI.

```
client = JIRA::Client.new(
  username: username,
  password: password,
  site: 'https://foo.com/',
  context_path: '',
  auth_type: :basic)

puts client.request('HEAD', '/')
```

Comment: what API that web service offers to authenticate user?  There are variety of authentications when it comes to Web services - what is nature of your web service - is it a REST API?  If it uses a HTTP BASIC AUTH, then, look at this http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html  and search for `Basic Authentication`

Comment: This is a prime case for a `HEAD /` request.

Comment: @WandMaker  Yes it is a REST API, I think the authentication is 'basic'

Comment: `HEAD /` and `GET /` are giving me errors... I am still trying to make sure I am using them correctly, however.

Comment: @WandMaker I like the look of that link you posted; I am trying that.

Comment: Ahhhh I see what the problem is. `HEAD/` and `GET /` are returning [302 Found](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302), but the JIRA RequestClient object that is handling the request raises an exception if the return is not in the 200s. I need to find a better way of checking the credentials I guess.

Answer (score 0):

https://jira.foo.no/rest/api/2/search?maxResults=1

Gets the latest issue that you have rights to see. If you can't you will get a forbidden or unauthorized HTML page